# Need help identifying planes, near Toronto

Tags: aircraft-identification

[image]
[image]
[image]
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this?  Idle curiosity?

Comment: Could you please split these questions up (one question per plane you want to identify, multiple pictures for the *same* plane are OK)?

Answer (score 4):

The last one is almost undoubtedly a [Pilatus PC-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-12) operated by [Ornge](https://www.ornge.ca/about-us/our-fleet#ourFleet).

Answer (score 4):

Top one's a Convair 580 and the middle one's a Challenger 300 business jet.